# при запуске gulp выдает ошибку

Tags: html, css, gulp

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
Error in plugin "sass"
Message:
    node_modules\@fancyapps\fancybox\dist\jquery.fancybox.css
Error: "env(safe-area-inset-right)" is not a number for `max'
        on line 485 of node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.css, in function `max`
        from line 485 of node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.css
        from line 2 of app/scss/_libs.scss
        from line 4 of app/scss/blog-one.scss
>>         padding: 75px max(44px, env(safe-area-inset-right)) max(25px, env(sa
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы избежать ошибки с функцией `max()`, нужно перевести строковое значение в выражение с помощью функции Sass `unquote()`:

Объявите так:

```css
@supports(padding: unquote('max(0px)')) {
  padding: 75px unquote('max(#{$susy-gutter-width}, env(safe-area-inset-left))');  
}
```

[Источник](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/2153)